# Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory no apparent cause

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am really struggling with an issue with spring boot and hibernate. I am getting this error:

```
AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
```

I was thinking that the app can't connect to the mysql database, but that does not seem to be the case because flyway is able to connect and run migration scripts.

```
[INFO ] 2020-01-21_11:18:39.293 [main] VersionPrinter - Flyway Community Edition 5.0.7 by Boxfuse
[INFO ] 2020-01-21_11:18:39.304 [main] HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
[INFO ] 2020-01-21_11:18:39.534 [main] HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
[INFO ] 2020-01-21_11:18:39.548 [main] DatabaseFactory - Database: jdbc:mysql://someIpHere:3306/someDatabaseNameHere (MySQL 5.6)
[INFO ] 2020-01-21_11:18:40.357 [main] DbValidate - Successfully validated 354 migrations (execution time 00:00.729s)
[INFO ] 2020-01-21_11:18:40.434 [main] DbMigrate - Current version of schema `someDatabaseNameHere `: 339
[WARN ] 2020-01-21_11:18:40.434 [main] DbMigrate - outOfOrder mode is active. Migration of schema `someDatabaseNameHere` may not be reproducible.
[INFO ] 2020-01-21_11:18:40.438 [main] DbMigrate - Schema `someDatabaseNameHere ` is up to date. No migration necessary.
[INFO ] 2020-01-21_11:18:40.622 [main] LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[INFO ] 2020-01-21_11:18:40.640 [main] LogHelper - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
```

The weird part is that if i run the exact same jar on another machine, it works. The logs look the same until i get the error.

Error logs:

```
[INFO ] 2020-01-21_11:18:40.622 [main] LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[INFO ] 2020-01-21_11:18:40.640 [main] LogHelper - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
[INFO ] 2020-01-21_11:18:40.718 [main] Version - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.14.Final}
[INFO ] 2020-01-21_11:18:40.720 [main] Environment - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
[INFO ] 2020-01-21_11:18:40.764 [main] Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
[INFO ] 2020-01-21_11:18:41.242 [main] Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
[WARN ] 2020-01-21_11:18:42.253 [main] AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
[INFO ] 2020-01-21_11:18:42.254 [main] HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
[INFO ] 2020-01-21_11:18:42.264 [main] HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
[INFO ] 2020-01-21_11:18:42.266 [main] StandardService - Stopping service [Tomcat]
```

No error logs:

```
[INFO ] 2020-01-21_12:19:31.394 [main] LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[INFO ] 2020-01-21_12:19:31.417 [main] LogHelper - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
[INFO ] 2020-01-21_12:19:31.510 [main] Version - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.14.Final}
[INFO ] 2020-01-21_12:19:31.512 [main] Environment - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
[INFO ] 2020-01-21_12:19:31.564 [main] Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
[INFO ] 2020-01-21_12:19:31.986 [main] Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
[INFO ] 2020-01-21_12:19:34.093 [main] LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[INFO ] 2020-01-21_12:19:34.499 [main] cluster - Cluster created with settings {hosts=[someHost:27017, someHost:27017, someHost:27017, someHost:27017, someHost:27017], mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
[INFO ] 2020-01-21_12:19:34.500 [main] cluster - Adding discovered server someHost:27017 to client view of cluster
```

I'm really stuck on this. I can't find an actual cause for the PersistenceException, even when running with logging level TRACE. As well, i can't find this exact exception behaviour anywhere on the internet, most of the time it's related to a bad config and the logs provide additional details. It has to be something related to the machine, but i can't figure out what and i can't get any more information from the logs.

Comment: just guessing here: maybe a maven cache problem with the wrong hibernate version? did u try to remove .m2 directory (or only the hibernate part)  and re-install all dependencies on the affected machine?

Comment: Check your java version and make sure you can reach the database from both machines.

Comment: The build is done on one machine then the jar is copied to the machines where its run, so it's the exact same jar running on both.

Comment: Java version is the same on both machines, and database access is allowed on both machines. The machine that fails access database with flyway before stoping.

Answer (score 0):

if you are running it on an external server, then download latest version of Tomcat.it could be version mismatch.[this might help you](https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-registration/issues/89)

Comment: Unfortunately it's using spring-boot so it can't be this.